# React not re-rendering after sorting

Tags: reactjs, sorting, react-hooks

I displayed a list of data from `const array`, and then I want to sort the `array` then update it, after that I expect there will be a re-renders, but it's not happening.

Is there something wrong here? thanks before

```
const array = [];

const finalData = (lastData) => {
    array.push(lastData);
    dispatch({ type: "LAST_DATA", payload: array });
  };

const sortID = (params) => {
    if (params === "asc") {
      array.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.id - b.id;
      }); 
    } else if (params === "des") {
      array.sort((a, b) => {
        return b.id - a.id;
      }); 
    }
  };
```

Comment: set array as a state variable. Re-rendering will happen when a state changes

Comment: For normal variable react doesn't react (re-render), it only reacts for some change in state variables.